# serviceLocator is null

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-servicemanager

```
class CustomSawException extends Exception implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, SawExceptionInterface
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function test(){
        $this->serviceLocator->get('SomeThing');
    }

    /**
     * Set service locator
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    /**
     * Get service locator
     *
     * @return ServiceLocatorInterface
     */
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
```

The exception that is thrown for this is:

> call of get() on null

I could not figure out why it is throwing exception?
`ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` should have injected the `ServiceLocator`?

Comment: "... is the exception thrown for this"... when? How are you calling this class? The service locator can only be injected if the service manager is instantiating the class.

Answer (score 1):

> `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` should have injected the `ServiceLocator`?

I am not so sure about that, in the latest versions of ZF2 this interface is deprecated.

Read also [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/issues/89#issuecomment-191404454) or [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807588/zf2-servicelocatorawareinterface-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-version) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because you don't use the `ServiceManager` to instantiate this service.

The `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` works only if this service is called via the `ServiceManager`.

If you use

```
new CustomSawException();
```

Outside of the ServiceManager, then the AwareInterface can't set the ServiceLocator.

You should declare this service as an invokable if it doesn't have dependencies, or factories in the other case.